# Qlik sense - Decile analysis with filter

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am using below logic from https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Decile-analysis/td-p/1223944.

=Aggr(

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.1), 10,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.2), 9,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.3), 8,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.4), 7,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.5), 6,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.6), 5,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.7), 4,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.8), 3,

if(Sum(Profit) <= fractile(TOTAL Aggr(Sum(Profit), Customer), 0.9), 2, 1))))))))), Customer)

However , I want to create a filter to only show 10% or 20%  or 30% customer. How can I create this filter.

After I create a filter pane by using this logic. When I select 10% it will continue the divide 10 part from the 10% of customer. The user can't identify they already select 10%.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you'd need to do here is add a set expression like **`{1}`** to your `Aggr()` function so that the your expression isn't affected by user selections, including in the filter pane itself:

[image: Screenshot GIF showing result of new Set Expression]

You can read more about the `1` Set Identifier on [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-identifiers.htm).